# Covariance zero does not imply independence - but what does it imply?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, covariance

As is [well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/simple-examples-of-uncorrelated-but-not-independent-x-and-y) [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333477/arguing-two-random-variables-are-not-independent-and-showing-their-covariance-is), there are [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630622/zero-covariance-but-not-independent-normally-distributed-random-variable-x-a) [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215345/uncorrelated-but-not-independent-random-variables) of (pairs of) random variables which have covariance zero, but which are not independent.

However, I'm wondering whether there are any general theorems about what having covariance zero *does* imply.   Are there theorems that say something like, "Covariance zero, under additional hypothesis H, implies the following relationship between $X$ and $Y$," or is there essentially no possible general relationship?

By the way, although for [certain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746028/independent-random-variables-are-uncorrelated-in-general-uncorrelated-random-v) [types](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337063/normal-distribution-connection-between-independence-and-covariance?rq=1) of distributions/families the implication "Covariance zero implies independent" is valid, that is not the kind of theorem I am asking about.  What relationship can there be that is *short* of full independence?  Any reasonable hypothesis H would be interesting to me, as would references to online resources or standard references.

Comment: I suppose you're not looking for results of the form "$X$ uncorrelated with $Y$ $\implies$ $\operatorname{Var}(X\pm Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$" or "$X,Y$ uncorrelated with $Z$ $\implies$ $X\pm Y$ uncorrelated with $Z$"?

Comment: You are right that that is weaker than I was hoping for (follows basically from definition of variance), but then again you didn't add an additional hypothesis H so I suppose that would be expected.  Ideal would be a theorem that has an equivalence for how strong an addition hypothesis would have to be in order to say more - for instance, that essentially there is only independent and dependent, with no gradations between.

Comment: @kcrisman do you know entropy? independence is equivalent to $H(X|Y) = H(X)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I know of entropy but haven't thought of it in a long time, nor really used it much.  You could make a more detailed version of this an answer, but keep in mind it is answering a different question; I asked what covariance zero implies (since it doesn't imply independence), not what other things might imply independence.  Unless there is some relationship between entropy and covariance not mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy)?

Comment: @kcrisman ha! I read your question as "but what does imply it".

Answer (score 6):

The covariance is just **one** number computed from two random variables. You cannot expect it to capture much information.

Saying that the covariance is zero is one equation; by comparison, saying that two RVs are independent is a huge amount of equations: one for each couple of real numbers! It is very strict.

All you can say when the covariance is zero is that a linear regression on a sample large enough will give you a horizontal line: you cannot predict the value of one variable from the other based on a linear model.

I would be happy to learn, but I'm afraid that not much more can be said.

Comment: Well, that was why I asked for "given some hypothesis H".  Clearly for certain types of random variables there is enough "extra" information - though see [this post](http://probability.ca/jeff/teaching/uncornor.html) for a warning about what "enough" extra information is.  So I figure maybe there is also some possible theoretical source, though I take the point that it would have to be a fairly strong condition to imply anything very close to independence.  But maybe there is something else it could imply.

Comment: $H(X)-H(X|Y)$ is just one number, and it captures independence

Comment: It's not the answer I'm looking for so I'm not accepting, but you deserve the bounty for this for the effort :)

Comment: @kcrisman Well, thanks, and if you ever get a more satisfactory answer, let me know (again, I'll be happy to learn), and I'll transfer the bounty to that answer.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that was possible.  I think you get to keep it even in that unlikely event, though I guess you don't need the rep :)

Comment: I added a similar answer haha, before reading yours. Good intuition!

Answer (score 0):

Think about it in terms of points scattered on a plane. When covariance $=0$, you are saying that you cannot construct a linear curve between those points on the plane but you can still construct some "curve" joining the points hence, independence is not $0$. But when independence is $0$, this means we cannot construct any curve joining any set of points, hence there is no covariance whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

The opposite to lack of correlation is full correlation. Typically, partial or full correlation between two events without dependence occurs when there is a third intevening variable. For example suppose there is a partial correlation between my time of waking and high tide. this may be explained by the fact that I need to get to work early in the morning and at my longditude  high tide tends to occur in the morning.  In this case time is the intervening variable.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a *mathematical* possible formulation here.